# Time it takes to reboot a Linux server

Tags: linux, time, reboot

Is there a way to work out how long it would take to reboot a Linux server? To clarify, the time from the reboot command starts to when the server is back up and running (ie all services started, users can log on etc).

I tried looking at syslog but that seems to get rotated too quickly.

To the nearest minute would suffice.

OS = CentOS & Ubuntu

Update: if there isn't a simple way - perhaps what would be a way to capture this data for future use.

Comment: what logs are you looking at, and how many days/weeks after a reboot? Does your CentOS/Ubuntu versions save /var/log/dmesg* files?

Comment: While I meant for my question to be more generic - the server I'm looking at has been up for nearly 400 days. Yes, we are saving dmesg.

Comment: from the dmesg file, you can at least see how long the actual boot of linux took, but it is not possible to see how long it took from shutdown until the bootloader was complete.

Comment: IMHO, there is no reliable way to measure the time for reboot to complete. there are many factors which add to the unpredictability, for example, there could be a filesystem check (fsck) forced during the reboot where the delay is unpredictable due to number and size of disks/ partitions involved. if we ignore such abnormal events, the other factors which need to be accounted for - whats the default runlevel? are your users logging in via ssh/ remote X11/ vnc etc ?

Comment: @nagu - most of those things stay the same or are manually changed (ie you can factor in the additional time). You can tell when a fsck will be forced and again factor in additional time. Generally a server will take the same amount of time to reboot each time - I was looking for a guide not an exact measure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're on CentOS 7+ or Ubuntu 15.04+ which both come with systemd. Systemd has some great tools for figuring out how long your system took to boot along with some visualizations to see why.

For the most basic output just run `systemd-analyze` and you'll get a nice summary like so

```
Startup finished in 853ms (kernel) + 3min 50.610s (initrd) + 10.345s (userspace) = 4min 1.809s
```

That can tell you how much time your last boot took once systemd was started. That doesn't take into account BIOS/hardware initialization or GRUB timeouts but should be accurate for actual OS boot time.

If you want to figure out why the OS is taking so long try `systemd-analyze blame` which will give you a chart of services from longest running to shortest. eg from my system

```
3min 49.219s systemd-cryptsetup@luks\x2d62611c1c\x2d74ab\x2d4be9\x2d8990\x2d41c0fd863b5a.service
      5.315s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      3.084s systemd-udev-settle.service
      2.275s plymouth-start.service
      2.256s docker.service
      1.819s powertop.service
       778ms firewalld.service
       676ms dev-mapper-fedora\x2droot.device
       621ms abrtd.service
       493ms lvm2-monitor.service
```

Looks like 3 of the 4 minutes it takes to my boot my laptop is because I have an encrypted drive.

Finally, with `systemd-analyze critical-chain` you can see a chain of events that are considered "critical" to get the system booted. From the [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-analyze.html) critical means "time-critical chain of units". This is because systemd parallelizes a lot of services. This will list the units that have to wait for another unit and how long it took to start.

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @10.336s
└─multi-user.target @10.323s
  └─docker.service @4.900s +2.256s
    └─network.target @4.868s
      └─wpa_supplicant.service @4.828s +14ms
        └─dbus.service @3.753s
          └─basic.target @3.749s
            └─sockets.target @3.749s
              └─docker.socket @3.741s +6ms
                └─sysinit.target @3.737s
                  └─systemd-update-utmp.service @3.726s +10ms
                    └─auditd.service @3.713s +9ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @3.617s +82ms
                        └─fedora-import-state.service @3.568s +36ms
                          └─local-fs.target @3.560s
                            └─run-user-42.mount @5.753s
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @383ms
                                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @301ms +80ms
                                  └─kmod-static-nodes.service @268ms +10ms
                                    └─system.slice
                                      └─-.slice
```

You can also do some cool stuff by exporting your boot tree to a picture to email it or plot it with svg. See the man page for more details or [this related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/617398/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-execution-tree-of-systemd) for a few more details.

Comment: +1 - thanks!  I'm using CentOS 7 but ... Ubuntu 14.04 ie upstart.

Comment: Why does `-` is replaced by `\x` in those mountpoints?

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav Not with only `\x` but with `\x2d` - and the `-` character is encoded in ASCII as 45, or 2d in hexadecimal. The name of a systemd mount unit should reflect the mount point of the filesystem with slashes in the pathname converted to minus signs - and if the pathname already contains minus signs, those existing minus signs need to be converted to *something else* so that the pathname of the mount point can be recovered without any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

**Asked 7 years, 4 months ago**

It will depend on the **server** being used, and the time it can take during its BIOS/EFI initialization as well as any **RAID disk initialization**; these two are the big time hitters that I experience.  But there could be other stuff happening, eating up time, all independent of Linux.

RHEL/Centos 7 and later, during boot can often hang on systemd waiting for network, if you are at work and have a corporate internet and sometimes the network switch/router does not immediately grant a dhcp ip address to your server, that can eat at least 30 seconds.

The simplest way to determine reboot time to be expected is to putty in over ssh, and type reboot.  From that point of `reboot <enter>` mark the time, and then from another window have a `ping myserver` going and wait until you get a response.  The difference there is your time to expect, do that many times, see how much it varies.

Once the ping starts responding, that doesn't necessarily mean you can immediately log in, as other services like SSH and GDM haven't started yet, but typically do within ~5 seconds, but you would find out simply if you can successfully log in.  Then that time from successful login till when you hit enter after reboot is your time.

Also, upon shutdown after typing `reboot` there can be a significant delay if data has to be written to disk, or some NFS service has to time out.

Many legitimate things can happen during shutdown and boot that can eat up some time.  When using SLES 11.4, was EXT4 files system opposed to RHEL 7/8 using XFS, I would experience `fsck has not been run in ~30 days` or some cr@p so if the server hadn't been rebooted for 100+ days which was not uncommon then that fsck that ran on boot could take 30 minutes if it was a huge spinning disk.

For what I experience I know generally less than 5 minutes is what to expect, ~3 minutes for server bios and disk raid, less than 1:30 for linux from grub menu for RHEL 7/8.  If 10 minutes goes by then I go to the server room and look what's happening on the console (or look at it over IPMI or idrac) to see what's happening.